# connect to mongodb from docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

i have a MongoDB running in my host with ip 127.0.0.1:27017 . I need to connect to my MongoDB from the docker image. so I try with these addresses:

```
localhost:27017

0.0.0.0:27017
```

but I get connection refused. is it about mongodb auth ?I didnt enable mongodb authentication on my host yet.

Comment: From the perspective if the running Docker container `localhost` is the container, not your docker host. Check out this post on one possibel way to connect to the Docker host: https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-host-machine-from-within-docker-container/14248/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ralf said in your comments, "localhost" from inside your container refers to the container itself.

An option to get around this is to also run MongoDB in a container, and then use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to run both containers and have them talk to each other.

For example, your (stripped-down, incomplete) `docker-compose.yml` file would look something like:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.0.11-xenial
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  your-app:
    # settings dependant on whatever your app is
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

Then when you are trying to connect via your application, you can connect using `mongodb://<user>:<pass>@mongo/YourDatabase`, since Docker will map `mongo` onto your `mongo` service.

Comment: So is there actually now way of connecting to a db that is running in the docker host? The only way I was able to get it working was by binding 0.0.0.0 and using the full host static IP in the mongo db url. But of course this is a security issue, so I don't want that.

Comment: The only way I know is the docker-compose approach described above, but that only works if your app and database are both running in the same virtual network created by Docker (e.g. by launching both via docker-compose).